# websrcaping html <time class=""></time> with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am building a webscraper for myself to scrape financial data and news from reuters.
So far it works like a charm, except for times / dates. Example:
on
https://www.reuters.com/companies/WDIG.DE/profile
is a Event Box like this one:
[image]

The Date "Apr 30, 2020" is contained in the source like this:

```
<time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__white___32MyF TextLabel__regular___2X0ym EventLabel-date-4_Sun">Apr 30, 2020</time>
```

But

```
result = requests.get(site)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
soup.find('time', {'class': 'TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__white___32MyF TextLabel__regular___2X0ym EventLabel-date-4_Sun'}).text
```

returns nothing i.e. the data i want (Apr 30, 2020) is not in the response i get from my request.
Anybody knows how to make this work?

Comment: If you were to print the contents of `soup` entirely to a notepad, are you able to see that `time` tag with the date text inside it??

Comment: This gives me the time tag, but without the date text inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 code snippets here, the first one is what you've done.

**Snippet 1:**

```
import requests
import bs4

site = "https://www.reuters.com/companies/WDIG.DE/profile"
result = requests.get(site)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
with open('soup_1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
print(soup.find('time', {'class': 'TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__white___32MyF TextLabel__regular___2X0ym EventLabel-date-4_Sun'}).text)
```

output:

```
<time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__white___32MyF TextLabel__regular___2X0ym EventLabel-date-4_Sun"></time>
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
driver.get(site)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

with open('soup_2.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())

driver.quit()
print("done")
```

output:

```
<time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__white___32MyF TextLabel__regular___2X0ym EventLabel-date-4_Sun">Apr 30, 2020</time>
```

for selenium to work, you'll need to download [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) and ensure that it resides in the same location as that of your script.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! So there is no way to do it with bs4 alone?

Comment: I don't think so if it's dynamic content running due to the JS on the webpage, just the requests library, and bs4 would be unable to pull all the data.